# Pattern Matching in Columns

Tags: perl, bash, unix, sed, awk

**File 1**

```
A11;F1;BMW
A23;F2;BMW
B12;F3;BMW
H11;F4;JBW
```

**File 2**

```
P01;A1;0;0--00  ;123;456;150
P01;A11;0;0--00  ;123;444;208
P01;B12;0;0--00  ;123;111;36
P01;V11;0;0--00  ;123;787;33.9
```

**Output**

```
-;-;-;P01;A1;0;0--00  ;123;456;150
A11;F1;BMW;P01;A11;0;0--00  ;123;444;208
B12;F3;BMW;P01;B12;0;0--00  ;123;111;36
-;-;-;P01;V11;0;0--00  ;123;787;33.9
```

**I TRIED**

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next }{ if($1 in a) {p=$1;$1="";print a[p],$0}}' File1 File2
```

But didnt work.

Basically I want to get the details from FILE 1 and compare with FILE2 (master list) .

**Example :**

A1 in FILE2 was not available in FILE1 , so in output file we have “-“ for 1st three fields and rest from FILE2 . Now, we have A11 and we got the detail in FILE1. So we write details of A11 from both File 1 & 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual Perl way: use a **hash** to remember the master list:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash;

open my $MASTER, '<', 'File1' or die $!;
while (<$MASTER>) {
    chomp;
    my @columns = split /;/;
    $hash{$columns[0]} = [@columns[1 .. $#columns]];
}
close $MASTER;

open my $DETAIL, '<', 'File2' or die $!;
while (<$DETAIL>) {
    my @columns = split /;/;
    if (exists $hash{$columns[1]}) {
        print join ';', $columns[1], @{ $hash{$columns[1]} }, q();
    } else {
        print '-;-;-;';
    }
    print;
}
close $DETAIL;
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do this in Perl, personally, but since everyone and their mother is giving you a Perl solution, here's an alternative:

Provided that the records in each file have a consistent number of fields, and provided that the records in each file are sorted by the "join" field in lexicographic order, you can use `join`:

```
join -1 1 -2 2 -t ';' -e - -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7' -a 2 File1 File2
```

Explanation of options:

- `-1 1` and `-2 2` mean that the "join" field (`A11`, `A23`, etc.) is the first field in `File1` and the second field in `File2`.
- `-t ';'` means that fields are separated by `;`
- `-e -` means that empty fields should be replaced by `-`
- `-o '1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7'` means that you want each output-line to consist of the first three fields from `File1`, followed by the first seven fields from `File2`. (This is why this approach requires that the records in each file have a consistent number of fields.)
- `-a 2` means that you want to include every line from `File2` in the output, even if there's no corresponding line from `File1`. (Otherwise it would only output lines that have a match in both files.)

Answer (score 2):

With Perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my %file1;
open (my $f1, "<", "file1") or die();
while (<$f1>) {
  chomp;
  my @v = (split(/;/))[0];
  $file1{$v[0]} = $_; 
}
close ($f1);
open (my $f2, "<", "file2") or die();
while (<$f2>) {
  chomp;
  my $v = (split(/;/))[1];
  if (defined $file1{$v}) {
    print "$file1{$v};$_\n";
  } else {
    print "-;-;-;$_\n";
  }
}
close ($f2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done conveniently in a one-line program as it involves reading two input files, however the problem isn't difficult

This program reads all the lines from `file1`, and uses the first field as a key to store the line in a hash

Then all the lines from `file2` are read and the second field used as a key to access the hash. The `//` defined-or operator is used to print either element's value is printed if it exists, or the default string if not

Finally the current line from `file2` is printed

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

open my $fh, '<', 'file1' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my $key = (split /;/)[0];
  $data{$key} = $_;
}

open $fh, '<', 'file2' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  my $key = (split /;/)[1];
  print $data{$key} // '-;-;-;', $_;
}
```

**output**

```
-;-;-;P01;A1;0;0--00  ;123;456;150
A11;F1;BMWP01;A11;0;0--00  ;123;444;208
B12;F3;BMWP01;B12;0;0--00  ;123;111;36
-;-;-;P01;V11;0;0--00  ;123;787;33.9
```

Comment: @TLP: I agree. I *never* do that dammit! Fixed

Answer (score 1):

A perl solution might include the very nice module [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV). If so, you might extract the values into a hash, and later use that hash for lookup. When looking up values, you would insert blank values `-;-;-;` for any undefined values in the lookup hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $lookup = "file1.csv";   # whatever file is used to look up fields 0-2
my $master = "file2.csv";   # the file controlling the printing

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
        sep_char    => ";", 
        eol         => $/,  # to add newline to $csv->print()
        quote_space => 0,   # to avoid adding quotes 
    });

my %lookup;

open my $fh, "<", $lookup or die $!;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    $lookup{$row->[0]} = $row;    # add entire row to specific key
}
open $fh, "<", $master or die $!; # new $fh needs no close

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    my $extra = $lookup{$row->[1]} // [ qw(- - -) ]; # blank row if undef
    unshift @$row, @$extra;       # add the new values
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, $row);   # then print them
}
```

**Output:**

```
-;-;-;P01;A1;0;0--00  ;123;456;150
A11;F1;BMW;P01;A11;0;0--00  ;123;444;208
B12;F3;BMW;P01;B12;0;0--00  ;123;111;36
-;-;-;P01;V11;0;0--00  ;123;787;33.9
```